# Pandas - Python - Lookup functions - Need walk through

Tags: python, pandas, function, lookup

I'm having trouble creating two functions that seem very easy, however, I keep receiving errors.

I have a dataframe (df) with several columns including 'stock' which is a list of tickers and 'close', which is the closing price for the ticker. There are ten or so tickers in the data with closing prices going back several months (total rows = 1000).

**Problem 1: Function with two parameters: 'df' which is a dataframe and 'price' which is a float.** 
*Task: Return (don't print) all data with close price less than 'price'* 
My code:

```
def get_high_low_close(df, symbol):
    '''
    Get highest and lowest close price of a stock.
    Parameters
    df: Pandas DataFrame containing data from Problem 1's solution
    symbol: stock symbol
    Returns
    returns two values, highest and lowest close price of the stock.
    '''
    symbol = df[df.stock =='AA']

    result = symbol.groupby('stock').agg({'close': ['max', 'min']})

get_high_low_close(df,symbol)
```

My output:
close
max    min
stock
AA     17.92  14.72

My output values are correct but I receive the following message: AssertionError: None != (17.92,14.72). My prof said I don't need to use groupby and that the argument symbol should be used to select rows but I'm still confused.

My second problem is similar and utilizes the same data: 
**Problem 2: Function with two parameters: 'df' which is a dataframe and 'symbol' which is a string.** 
*Task: Return (don't print) highest and lowest close price of stock represented by symbol.'*

I've tried many different codes but cannot get the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you should try and format your code a bit better by using `code` formatting

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more clarity, like the df.head(). I will use an example to make assumptions to help in solving the problem

```
#reconstructing your question and making use of assumptions

#symbol
symbol = 'GOOGL'

df = pd.read_csv(symbol+'.csv')


def get_high_low_close(df, symbol):
    '''
    Get highest and lowest close price of a stock.
    Parameters
    df: Pandas DataFrame containing data from Problem 1's solution
    symbol: stock symbol
    Returns
    returns two values, highest and lowest close price of the stock.
    '''
    #highest close price
    highest_close_price = df['Close'].max()
    #lowest closing price
    lowest_close_price = df['Close'].min()
    
    #return them
    return highest_close_price, lowest_close_price
    

get_high_low_close(df,symbol)

#prints (2118.6201170000004, 1054.130005)

#price
price = 1115.47859

def get_high_low_close(df, symbol):
    '''
    Get highest and lowest close price of a stock.
    Parameters
    df: Pandas DataFrame containing data from Problem 1's solution
    symbol: stock symbol
    Returns
    returns two values, highest and lowest close price of the stock.
    '''
    #create function to evaluate the price
    def close_price(cls_price):
        if cls_price < price:
            return price
        
    #use apply function to evaluate the closing prices
    close_lower_than_price = df['Close'].apply(lambda x: close_price(x))
    close_lower_than_price = close_lower_than_price.dropna(how = "any") #drop nan values
    
    return close_lower_than_price

get_high_low_close(df, symbol)
```

Returns closing prices less than the price

```
 """
    0    1115.47859
    2    1115.47859
    4    1115.47859
    7    1115.47859
    9    1115.47859
    """
```

Comment: Sam, this was perfect. Thank you!